# how to export mongodb without any wrapping with NumberInt(...)?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoexport

I want to export mongodb as json, here is a record:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"554f042c0e81bf483e4a4e2f"}, "batch":"3","bz":NumberInt(1)}
```

the problems is when I use json to loads it:

```
json.loads('{"_id":{"$oid":"554f042c0e81bf483e4a4e2f"}, "batch":"3","bz":NumberInt(1)}')
```

it returns `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`. This is because `json` can not deal with `NumberInt(1)`.

So how can I translate `NumberInt(1)` to `1` when I export?

Comment: which version of MongoDB are you using? When storing it `db.collection.insert({"_id":{"$oid":"554f042c0e81bf483e4a4e2f"}, batch":"3","bz":NumberInt(1)})` it stored as `{"_id":{"$oid":"554f042c0e81bf483e4a4e2f"}, batch":"3","bz":1}`

Comment: @dev mongo 3.0.3. the problem is I can only get it wrap with NumberInt

Comment: Your json is invalid on the batch key, it should be wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: @chridam thank you, it is a long json, so I delete some of them, then I made a mistake

Comment: I was about to jump in and say simply use `--pretty`. However, while this formats things like `NumberLong` correctly ( as `$numberlong` ) interestingly `NumberInt` does not come out that way :( Frankly you are going to need to either write your own export or pre-parse the text output in order to convert those strings to an appropriate format. ( you could just use `sed` with piped output ). For either case, take a look at [Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) for details and even [EJSON](https://github.com/primus/ejson) for the correct spec.

Comment: If someone has the time to check, I might wager than 2.X series versions of `mongoexport` might not have this problem. The 3.X series are complete re-writes of these tools. In some part to support the pluggable storage engine concept, and otherwise as a move to port these tools to the "go" language. I smell bugs here.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE] IF your mongo collection does not include NumberInt, and mongoexport creates a json document that includes NumberInt, this is a bug.
I leave my answer in case anyone has the same issue as I had.

It seems it was indeed a bug

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-741
that duplicates https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-681 that was fixed in 3.1.4

I tested with 3.1.6 (last dev release) and it works