# How to unmarshal json to struct with uint8

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

How do you unmarshal json into struct that contains a uint8? I am getting the error message `json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field A.test of type uint8`

In my struct I have

```
type A struct {
    Test  uint8  `json:"test omitempty" bson:"test"`
}
```

I inserted struct A into mongo and then I successfully do a mongo find and print out the collection struct A corresponds to. I can do a bson.MarshalExtJSON to convert the bson to json and then when I do a json.Unmarshal to convert json to struct A that is where I am failing.

Here is a sample golang playground that recreates the issue. I don't understand why this fails? How do I fix it?

https://play.golang.org/p/0HOAxsu166j

I see that unmarshal uses "float64, for JSON numbers" but I can't get float64 rather than uint8 to work either

Comment: Unmarshalling JSON to int8 [works fine](https://play.golang.org/p/xs_zVPyPNzU) but you seem to be trying to unmarshall a BSON string using the JSON parser?

Comment: Ok so the issue is that I have extendedJson and not plain JSON? I don't think calling it a BSON string is accurate

Comment: Sorry you are correct (just noted it was not plain old JSON and you used the BSON package) its extended JSON which means you are trying to decode the object ```{"$numberInt":"52"}``` to a uint8.

Comment: apparently related, based on this `$numberInt` thing: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30703171/1256452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Brits comment, I found that when I called bson.MarshalExtJSON I got extendedJson. json.Unmarshal() cannot read extendedJson like `{"$numberInt":"52"}` so that is why it was failing.

so to solve it I am using `bson.UnmarshalExtJSON()` rather than `json.Unmarshal()` to be able to unmarshal the extendedJSON into the struct