# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 13 (char 15)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, mongodb, python-2.7

I have a nested json file which I got from json.
I am trying to convert it in to csv through python code.

I tried all the possible way to convert it to csv but couldn't succeed.

I also followed previous question and solution but didn't work for me.

My json format is

```
{ 
    "d1" : ("value1"), 
    "d2" : (value2-int), 
    "d3" : [
        {
            "sub-d1" : sub-value1(int), 
            "sub-d2" : sub-value2(int), 
            "sub-d3" : sub-value3(int), 
            "sub-d4" : [
                {
                    "sub-sub-d1" : "sub-sub-value3", 
                    "sub-sub-d2" : sub-value3(int)
                }, 
                {
                    "sub-sub-d1" : sub-sub-value3(int), 
                    "sub-sub-d2" : "sub-sub-value3"}
                 ]
                        ], 
            "sub-d5" : "sub-value4", 
            "sub-d6" : "sub-value5"
        }
    ], 
    "d4" : "value3", 
    "d5" : "value4", 
    "d6" : "value5, 
    "d7" : "value6"
}

{ another entry with same pattern..and so on}
```

Some of the value and sub value has integers and str + int.

What I tried

```
import json
import csv
import requests

with open('./data/inverter.json', 'r') as myfile:
    json_data = myfile.read()

def get_leaves(item, key=None):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        leaves = {}
        for i in item.keys():
            leaves.update(get_leaves(item[i], i))
        return leaves
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        leaves = {}
        for i in item:
            leaves.update(get_leaves(i, key))
        return leaves
    else:
        return {key : item}

# First parse all entries to get the complete fieldname list
fieldnames = set()

for entry in json_data:
    fieldnames.update(get_leaves(entry).keys())

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=sorted(fieldnames))
    csv_output.writeheader()
    csv_output.writerows(get_leaves(entry) for entry in json_data)
```

This one saves all my data in single column with split values.

I tried to use :
https://github.com/vinay20045/json-to-csv.git

but this also didn't work.

I also tried to parse and do simple trick with following code:

```
with open("./data/inverter.json") as data_file:
  data = data_file.read()
  #print(data) 
  data_content = json.loads(data)   
  print(data_content)
```

but it throws an error : 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 13 (char 15)'

Can any one help me to convert my nested json to csv ?

It would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The data you have here doesn't look like actual JSON - for example, JSON syntax does not have parenthesis, and items like sub-sub-value3 are not surrounded by quotation marks (assuming they are intended to be strings). Where did this data come from?

Comment: Sorry, some of them are integers , I forgot to mentioned that.

Comment: The point still stands: parenthesis () are not valid JSON and will cause exactly the message you are getting. The reason I'm asking where the data comes from is that maybe it's some special customized version of JSON that could be parsed in a standard way given the right library.

Comment: I got your point, how can I avoid this () parenthesis? I checked this huge json file and I saw so many value inside of parentheses() ..e.g.. NumberInt(10021).....

Comment: Where did the data come from?  If it was from MongoDB, do you have the option to export it in a different way?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I solved the problems. As you said it was not valid, I used Pymongo to extract data from DB. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the NumberInt(234234) issue you describe was a bug in MongoDB: [how to export mongodb without any wrapping with NumberInt(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703171/how-to-export-mongodb-without-any-wrapping-with-numberint)

If you cannot fix it by upgrading MongoDB, I can recommend preprocessing the data with regular expressions and parsing it as regular JSON after that.

For the sake of example, let's say you've got "test.json" that looks like this, which is valid except for the NumberInt(...) stuff:

```
{
    "d1" : "value1",
    "d2" : NumberInt(1234),
    "d3" : [
        {
            "sub-d1" : 123,
            "sub-d2" : 123,
            "sub-d3" : 123,
            "sub-d4" : [
                {
                    "sub-sub-d1" : "sub-sub-value3",
                    "sub-sub-d2" : NumberInt(123)
                },
                {
                    "sub-sub-d1" : 43242,
                    "sub-sub-d2" : "sub-sub-value3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "d4" : "value3",
    "d5" : "value4",
    "d6" : "value5",
    "d7" : "value6"
}
```

You could import this into Python as follows:

```
import re
import json

with open("test.json") as f:
    data = f.read()

# This regular expression finds/replaces the NumberInt bits with just the contents
fixed_data = re.sub(r"NumberInt\((\d+)\)", r"\1", data)

loaded_data = json.loads(fixed_data)

print(json.dumps(loaded_data, indent=4))
```

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks a lot. However your code also gave me same error. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @giblegarcham you're welcome! You should post your solution as a new answer so anyone else with the same problem can find it!